# Visual Studio - Generate UML from a c++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, uml

Currently I am reading though the cryengine gamecode. It is huge not very well documented. It would be really good if I could create an UML diagram from the project file.

I already found some tools to generate an UML diagram from c++ code, the problem is that the cryengine project is really huge and it would take a lot of time to do this.

Do you think this is possible?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Visual Studio has the build-in UML generator.
On Visual Studio project, select `Class View`, right click on the namespace, select `View Class Diagram`. It may take a while to generate UML diagrams if your project is big.
 Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: it doesn't seem to generate the assocaition like one to one, one to many.

Comment: When I right-click on a class in this window, I don't see the action "View Class Diagram", what should I do? (I'm working with Visual Studio 2017)

Comment: Even I do not see this option in Visual Studio 2017. I get **View Class Diagram** option when I right click on a header file, but I get an error saying **No such interface supported**.

Comment: If you have the installer of Visual Studio still somewhere lying around, you can open the installer, press the modify button in the installer, go to the "individual components" tab, scroll down and tick "Class Designer" which is right below "Code Tools"

Answer (score 5):

You may be disappointed by the result: a huge mess of C++ may render as an equally hugely complicated UML diagram.

Nevertheless, one tool that designed to help visualize large C++ code bases is [Understand](http://www.scitools.com/).

Comment: You were right. Inheritance is pretty decent but composition is a real mess http://i.imgur.com/Xk00w.jpg I'll give "understand" a try.

Comment: Can you suggest any free versions similar to this? Currently using Visual Studio built in Class diagram tool for a huge C++ project.