# MS VS2012 fails to export UML diagram as image

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I have generated my C++ project class diagram using Visual Studio 2012 **CLASS DIAGRAM** -> **Export Diagram as Image** .And I am getting the following error:

> specified cast is not valid

In the web I found that VS2012 Update 1 was supposed to fix this.I am today on update 4 and I still experience this issue.How can I fix it?

To generate the diagram I did the following:

Go to "Class View" panel ,select the namespace of my classes,right click select "View Class Diagram" .
Did it exactly as  [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13452507/visual-studio-generate-uml-from-a-c-project).

Comment: Can you provide code for reproducing this problem?

Comment: There is no code here.You generate the UML via the menu bar as I described.

Comment: Can you describe what you have done to reproduce the issue? Maybe post the image by cut'n'pasting it here (e.g. using the print key and MSPaint)?

Comment: I get a class diagram by right-clicking on a cpp file ("code") or a class in the class view (code again) and choosing "View Class Diagram". How do you get a class diagram without code? Or have you tried to generate code from the diagram? What's the result?

Comment: Ok,working on the update.

Comment: I do the same for two classes `A` and `B`, `B` inheriting from `A`. Works nicely. Please provide a [reproducable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What do you mean "works nicely"? Did you try to save to image as I explained?Did it save?What version of VS do you use?

Comment: VS2012 produced a png file containing the UML diagram of the two classes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62238/discussion-between-michael-iv-and-tobimcnamobi).

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue today in Visual Studio 2013 update 3.

I was able to generate an image by simply selecting all objects on the class diagram image and then hitting ctrl-c to copy.  Then opened up Word and hit paste.

It generated an image correctly.